# Create and set file extension using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Is it possible to set/force the file extension for a new file created via Google Apps Script?

I am running the following:

```
var c = DriveApp.createFile(getBlob());
c.setName("test.lic");
```

But the file always has a .bin extension (i.e. it becomes test.lic.bin when downloaded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try that:

```
  var blob = getBlob();
  blob.setContentType("application/octet-stream").setName("testFile.lic");
  DriveApp.createFile(blob);
```

I changed the content type but I don't belive it's necessary.